# ¿Cómo puedo corregir errores de enlaces permanentes en ngnix?

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu, nginx, azure

Estoy alojada en Azure, instalé un servidor Ubuntu en una máquina virtual, en él monté `Nginx` y posteriormente instalé `Wordpress`, quiero hacer cursos con el plugin `Tutor pro`, pero parece ser que no puedo ingresar a ninguna página de dichos cursos.
Quiero aclarar que es el único plugin activo que tengo.
Modifiqué todos los enlaces permanentes y no funcionó.
Al momento de ingresar a la parte de `?courses=matematicas` me carga perfectamente, pero al momento de tomar los cursos en cualquier tema, me arroja `404 Not Found nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)`.

He probado modificar el archivo `.htaccess` de la raíz añadiendo:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Y no funciona. Di permisos de lectura al grupo de Nginx `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/tu-sitio-web`, pero tampoco funciona.

Añadí este código que permite modificar y corregir el problema de los enlaces permanentes en la ruta `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` y tampoco:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
}
```

He intentado muchas cosas y no funciona.

Esta es la página: https://pruebate.eastasia.cloudapp.azure.com/?courses=matematicas
Por si gustan revisarla, puedo concederles permiso y acceso si me lo solicitan para que revisen a detalle, si me quisieran ayudar. (Tengo backups de todo, así que no es problema). Les agradeceré mucho si me ayudan a resolver este problema.

Answer (score 0):

aqui tu solucion amigo, me funciono perfectamente espero te sea de ayuda:

Para arreglar el error 404 al cambiar los enlaces permanentes en WordPress, usando NGINX como servidor web, simplemente tendremos que editar nuestro vhost, y añadir el código que facilito.

https://www.lopezgarijo.com/arreglar-permalinks-wordpress-nginx/

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/401032)